# Post data to server and then parse the HTML-code C#

Tags: c#, html, html-parsing

I'm trying to parse a website. The only problem is that the site dosen't use a specific URL to the site I wan't to parse. The content is being displayed to the site using JavaScript on the same webpage so the content is different depending on the searchquery.

Is it possible to choose a value from a dropdown-menu and then post that to the server and then parse the HTML-code in C#?

Clarification:The code is returned in HTML.
I know the name of the option from the dropdown i want to post, but how do I do that from code-behind?

Comment: If the HTML is generated with javascript, you'll need to execute the JS as well.

Answer (score 0):

Most sites do not really generate HTML in Javascript. Much more often you see Asp.Net sites where Javascript is used for a postback (and name of the dropdown is posted back in __EVENTTARGET field)

Then you can do the same in your application - you have to imitate filling the form - pass all the fields to the server including VIEWSTATE and EVENTTARGET.

Having said that, it might be against the site's terms of use.

Comment: Clarification:The code is returned in HTML.
I know the name of the option from the dropdown i want to post, but how do I do that from code-behind?

Answer (score 0):

[You definitely need to checkout Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/), it does exactly what you need. It is commonly used as a testing framework. However you can use it to manipulate HTML tags even when the website uses javascript.

**Note**: Selenium allows you to open and manipulate a website using a browser such as FireFox, Chrome, IE, etc. However, I think what you need here is to use the WebDriver, which manipulates the website without opening a browser. Most of my experience using Selenium is with Java, but I found multiple tutorials online for .net too.